# how to match # character in a url in nginx through location directive

Tags: nginx

How do I match a # character in a url using location directive? I understand that we can use regex(PCRE), but their docs say that :

> The location directive only tries to match from the first / after the hostname, to just before the first ? or #. (Within that range, it matches the unescaped url.)"

In short, How to match "example.com/#123456" using

```
location ~ [someregex] {
   return 200 "matched";
}
```

or with any other alternative

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple answer, you can't actually, because that part is never sent to the server to begin with, the only way to process this is to use Javascript, using `location.hash`

Comment: I forgot about my question entirely, I understood that the # part never gets sent to the server, fixed my problem with some additional JavaScript as you suggested sometime ago, Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can't because the ID hash isn't actually sent to the server, you might want to use GET variables like `example.com?p=1234` if you intend to direct to a certain page or use `location.hash` if you wish to direct to a location on the page (which is its intended use)

Good luck!